# Alarm feature in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to controll the **snooze and dismiss button** when the alarm sound in windows phone 7.

But i couldnt find any source code example on it.

Can anyone help me with it?

What i want is like when i **clicked on the snooze or dimiss button it will do something** such as the dismiss button will naviagte to another page.

And one more thing is that when the alarm is triggered can i set it to play some music??
Because the one that i have tried out does not play any music.

```
    private static void CreateAlarm(string title, string time)
    {
        var alarm = new Alarm(title)
        {
            Content = "You have a meeting with your team now.",
            BeginTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time),                 
        };

        ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
    }

    private static void ResetAlarm()
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Remove("MyAlarm");
    }

    private void SetAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string time = Convert.ToString(timePicker1.ValueString);
        CreateAlarm(txtTitle.Text, time);

    }

    private void ResetAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResetAlarm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Alarm` class has a `.Sound` property to controls the sound file that is played.

To use it, say you have Alarm.mp3 in your project under the Sounds folder with it's build action set to `Content`.

```
var alarm = new Alarm() {
  Sound = new Uri('Sounds/Alarm.mp3', UriKind.Relative)
}
```

There is no way to respond to snooze or dismiss that I have seen.

Comment: that mean the snooze and dismiss button that will appear when the alarm is sound would not be controlled at all??

Comment: that's correct. They are standard phone functions and will do what they want to do.